# Emulator won't boot in Eclipse? Issue using real Android device for code?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to Android programming, and *none* of my emulators work. They load, but freeze while booting up. Any ideas? My program is for 2.3.3, and I actually own an Android device, and is running 2.3.6, but when I try to load it for my phone, it says that there are "no compatible devices". Help?

Edit: Using Windows 8, and have already installed Google USB Driver.

Comment: Do you have a good hardware to run it? , also are you on linux or windows?

Comment: @LuisAlberto, Windows 8

Comment: The "no compatible devices" error means that your phone has a below api than the project require, also if you want to run the Android emulator you'll need a good machine.

Comment: I have a 5 year old Q6600 that runs an AVD just fine.  That said, have you looked into using a Genymotion VM rather than AVD?

Comment: @Pedantic, nope, like I said, new to doing this. Today is only my fourth day.

Comment: @LuisAlberto, phone's on 2.3.6, and my API is set to 2.3.3. Whats wrong?

Comment: Did you download usb_driver from sdk manager?

Comment: Google USB driver? Nope, doing that now.

Comment: Nope, still not working